# How to get the time difference between the two date input fields in laravel?

Tags: laravel

So I have two different date input fields and a duration field on the same form.
Now As soon as the start date and end date the fields are entered, i want the duration field to be automatically calculated as the difference between start date and end date (in days).

All of these in a same form.

```
<td><input type="date" name="program_start_date" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
<td><input type="date" name="program_end_date" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="program_duration" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

you can calucalate it by using jquery or js like below

```
<script>
        function diffDays(){
            const date1 = new Date($("input[name=program_start_date]").val());
            const date2 = new Date($("input[name=program_end_date]").val());
            const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
            const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
            $("input[name=program_duration]").val(diffDays + " days");
        }
    </script>
```

and call diffDays function on enddate change event
as below

```
<td><input type="date" name="program_start_date" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
            <td><input type="date" name="program_end_date" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" onchange="diffDays()" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="program_duration" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
```